# Bash+Python - encoded script's source shows up temporarily under /tmp

Tags: python, bash, encoding, pyinstaller

I have a bash script which is encoded in Python using the following code:

```
import tempfile
import subprocess
import zlib

with open("/root/test.sh") as inputfile:
    teststr = zlib.compress(inputfile.read()).encode('base64')
    print teststr
```

This gives me the encoded string which I then pass as a variable in my python script, like so (plz note, this is a sample script that installs `pip`):

```
piping="eJyNksFuwyAMhs/wFJ4qTdsBrG63HXLdY0yEEoKSAAJnXTvt3QdtNyWTWu2EkX//tj/Y3GHrPLYq95xz5zOpcXyLLj48fnLG2TTsXAKcc8IxaDViThq7kIqi6JneXcuxDbwaIuctZENzFBTCmIECXJpAPFAfvKhqtreGoCeK+QUxHqKT56wMyWJUelDWZMxhTtpgCarjyXARiq3cymdJKkl7BCF8ELo3ehDaJHKd04oMNM1y4K6borHlUpq4KMsJT839lrNiAseP9w6u2a991sUFyt8yzs77nBNluV8Kt4yWEJXf/dScmJ5QQKG94Ag3HmSNOKm9tI76uZU6TJW4qr1xUplMQh08JddiKam+dd5bc152+5+afy2/Gf8G8sjZTA=="
installpip=zlib.decompress(piping.decode('base64'))

with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile() as scriptfile:
        scriptfile.write(installpip)
        scriptfile.flush()
        subprocess.call(['/bin/bash', scriptfile.name])
```

This python script is then encoded using `pytinstaller 2.0`. When the installation is run, it runs fine but the encoded variable is decoded and stored temporarily in `/tmp` as `tmpXXXXX` and this is shown to be running while running `ps aux` and `top`.

How can this be avoided?

Comment: I don't think that you could avoid that.  You can get more control over the location of the temp file, though.  Try specifying `TMPDIR`.

Comment: Even if it didn't use /tmp, I doubt if you would be able to hide the code in any foolproof manner. One could open your pyinstaller package and decode the base64 encoded text.

Comment: @devnull - yes, that was one of the first things I did. So now the decoded bash is shown in the new temporary directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use a *named* temporary file, and instead pipe its contents in with `stdin`:

```
import tempfile, subprocess
installpip="echo 'hello'\n"

with tempfile.TemporaryFile() as scriptfile:
        scriptfile.write(installpip)
        scriptfile.flush()
        scriptfile.seek(0)
        subprocess.call(['/bin/bash', '-s'], stdin=scriptfile)
```

Of course this is not entirely bullet-proof either, but I'm sure you know that already.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use temporary files. Instead, [communicate](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate) with the process directly through a pipe:

```
import subprocess

content = "echo 'hello'\n"
p = subprocess.Popen(['/bin/bash', '-s'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
p.communicate(content)
```